# How to query a database on another machine from inside SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Let's say I have 5 computers on a LAN.

On each computer there is a database.

The databases are all set to connect using Windows Authentication.

All the computers have the same user name and password.

I would like to query the database on computer 2, from computer 1.

When I log into sql server management studio, if I search for the databases over the network, I can log into these databases directly. This works fine. However, I would prefer to simply run queries from computer 1 that runs on computer 2, 3, 4, or 5 at will by the way of the query itself instead of having to log into the engine each time.

I hope this make sense. I can't sort out a way to ask google this question.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use linked server functionality of SQL Server. Add computer 2,3,4,5 as linked servers on computer 1. Check this link for creating linked servers:- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ff772782%28v=sql.105%29.aspx#SSMSProcedure

Comment: This worked. It took a while to get the connection properties straight. I had to go in and enable TCP and named pipes and all that jazz and reboot the machines but it got working. 

One other question... how do I write the query to query that database instead of the main database?

Comment: You can query any database on linked server as follows:  select * from <linked-server-name>.<database-name>.<schema-name>.<table-name>